# Laptop replies to ping in sleep mode

Tags: windows, ping, icmp

Recently I got new company laptop with Windows 11 and noticed weird behaviour. When the computer is in sleep mode (screen blank, power led slowly fades in and out) the laptop still replies to network requests, including icmp echo requests and port scanning (nmap -sT). What's going on here and how do I get the classic behaviour back? I need a remote way to figure out if the computer is being used and until now I thought that ping is a perfect way to do that.

Additional info: computer is connected to power and network via USB3 docking station by HP. Network router is UPC Connect Box and there is another D-Link DGS-1008D switch between router and laptop. I am quite sure about the network address, tried both IPv4 and IPv6 (link local), in both cases unplugging the Ethernet cable from docking station stops ping replies.

Comment: Laptop is HP EliteBook 850 G8 - any other info missing? Or is there yet another reason for downvote?

Comment: I didn’t downvote you, but: as you discovered, ping is not a perfect way to check if a computer is being used.

Comment: Have you tried plugging the Ethernet cable into the laptop instead of the docking station?

Comment: Probably the [Modern Standby aka S0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby) crap? (aka laptop pretends to be a phone sleep mode by Intel AFAIK).

Comment: Last time I heard from an LTT video, S3 has been annihilated in many S0-supporting devices.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/overview-of-modern-standby-validation#verifying-if-a-system-is-modern-standby-capable

Comment: @DavidPostill Laptop does not have Ethernet port - I need to use docking station to have cable connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Sleep mode in Windows 11 is not what it used to be. I run this string in the Run console (Win+R) to actually put it to sleep:

`rundll32.exe powrprof.dll, SetSuspendState Sleep`

Comment: Does not work for me (kind of sleeps, but does not wake up), but that's probably because of firmware issues (no S3 standby support) on my laptop.

Comment: For me, it works but I need to wake it up with the power button.